# Applying an empty filter on the Active Excel Spreadsheet - C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

So, i'm parsing through a multitude of Excel files using C#, one of the things that my program is doing is re-applying the filters on the active sheet on the workbook. but i'm getting this error System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: '_AutoFilter method of Range class failed' when calling the .AutoFilter() method.

```
                var xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file.FullName);
                Worksheet xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets["Data"];
                xlWorkSheet.Range["A:Q"].AutoFilter();
```

Any Ideas on what could be wrong?

To elaborate more on the problem, i need to run this code on about 100+ workbooks and the sheets have between 10 to 20,000 lines, the script run through the sheets do a bunch of calculations to add 3 new columns, the only piece missing is adding those 3 new columns to the filters that are displayed in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Given that your fix worked without pointing to just the header row, I took down my answer.

Comment: ok! thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around with the my code i finally figured out a solution.

instead of using

`xlWorkBook.Sheets["Data"].Range["A:Q"].AutoFilter();`

i used this

`xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet.Range["A:Q"].AutoFilter();`

Why the first way don't work is beyond me, just posting my solution in case someone come across the same issue in the future.

Comment: Thank-you so much. I spent hours trying to make the "first way" work in my Excel VSTO Add-In, including by using a reference to the active sheet: `Excel.Worksheet objActiveSheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet; objActiveSheet.Range["XX:XX"].AutoFilter();`. In the end, only the "second way" worked: `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet.Range["XX:XX"].AutoFilter();`